# Asp core and Angular SSR

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, server-side-rendering, publish

How to create and publish an asp core project with angular ssr?
There are very few tutorials on this and almost none of them explain about publishing.

Comment: You can use Angular Universal, also there's Scully easier to use for already existing projects. If you prerender you need nothing to do extra. If you use SSR, you have to run the main.js in the server bundle, when deployed, be sure that dist/server/main.js up and running on the server you deployed.

Comment: Thanks,but i can not find full toturail about it.